# Change property while lazy loading tableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, lazy-loading

Context: I have a tableview with custom cells. Each cell has a button to download a resource. When a button is pressed all other buttons in the tableview should be disabled.

So my problem is that I can't get a reference to all the rows on the tableview since it is lazy loading. So when I try to access the other rows it fails because it doesn't have an object to add at the point where I start disabling the buttons.

Here is the code it may be more enlightening on my problem:

```
NSMutableArray *cells = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [mainTableView numberOfRowsInSection:1]; ++i) {
    WSVideoLibraryTableCell *addedCell = (WSVideoLibraryTableCell *)[mainTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:1]];
    NSLog(@"CELL ADDED: %@", addedCell);
    [cells addObject:addedCell];
}
if (stateEnabled) {
    for (WSVideoLibraryTableCell *cell in cells) {
        [[cell downloadButton] setEnabled:YES];
    }
}
else
{
    for (WSVideoLibraryTableCell *cell in cells) {
        [[cell downloadButton] setEnabled:NO];
    }
}
```

I tried adding some code that takes only the visible cells. `NSArray *array = [mainTableView visibleCells]` but then the problem is that the cells that weren't visible will have the button enabled and something weird happens with the rows that where visible, they appear again and again on the tableView (Something to do with lazy loading and changing them?)

Thanks a lot for comments or suggestions!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to have each object have its own `isEnabled` property, so that you can disable the objects themselves, and set a condition for the lazy loading to disable them according to that property.

Lazy loading is very helpful, and while for a trivial number of cells you won't notice a resource drain, you will as you increase the number of cells you're processing.

Comment: On the objects? I suppose you mean my customized cells. The property is already there since the button is inside the cells and getting its state is easy. But what I don't get is what you say about the condition for the lazy loading to disable them according to the property. How can I do that? Sorry I don't understand exactly how does the lazy loading works...

Comment: I am guessing you mean setting a bool for when the button is pressed to download. Then at the method of lazy loading (I suppose) `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I set the properties of the cell accordingly... I think that is what you meant I will try it, if not please correct me :)

Comment: I had assumed that each cell represented some object from a collection of objects(In your case maybe a `Resource` object that is itself a `UITableViewCell`). In that case you would just add a property to `Resource` that determined whether it was enabled or not. Then when you add the cell for a `Resource` object check its `Enabled` property and disable the cell accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this (imo) is to subclass UITableViewCell, add your fields to that object (ie your button), keep a list of all of those objects and then let lazy rendering handle the actual rendering. If you want to disable all of the buttons, you don't dip into the rendered cells, you just iterate over your list of objects disabling the buttons in each one.